# Entity metadata for role was not found

Tags: node.js, orm, nestjs, typeorm

I am stuck. Im using Nest.js and Type Orm. Have 2 entities which works without commented lines.

User:

```
@Entity('user')
export class UserEntity {

  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @Column({
    unique: true,
  })
  email: string;

  @Column({
    nullable: true,
  })
  password: string;

  // @OneToMany(type => PetEntity, pet => pet.user)
  // pets: PetEntity;
}
```

Pet:

```
@Entity('pet')
export class PetEntity {

  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  // @ManyToOne(type => UserEntity, user => user.pets)
  // user: UserEntity;
}
```

When i uncomment, receive an error `Error: Entity metadata for PetEntity#user was not found`
My ormConfig :

```
{
  "entities": ["dist/**/*.entity.js"]
}
```

I add every entity in my modules:

```
@Module({
  imports:
    [
      TypeOrmModule.forFeature([UserRepository]),
      TypeOrmModule.forFeature([PetRepository])
    ],
  controllers:[UserController],
  providers:[UserService]
})
export class UserModule {}
```

---

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([PetRepository]),
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([UserRepository])
  ],
  controllers: [PetController],
  providers: [PetService]
})
export class PetModule {
}
```

How to fixed it? 
I built relations as shown in the documentation https://typeorm.io/#/many-to-one-one-to-many-relations
Other internet solutions do not help me

Answer (score 0):

The only thing worked for me was that:

`index.ts`

```js
import { User } from "./entity/User";


createConnection({
  type: "mongodb",
  host: "192.168.0.101",
  port: 27017,
  database: "test",
  entities: [User],
}).then(async connection => {
```

I added `entities` property to `createConnection` and everything worked just fine.

I tried thinks like in this thread show, but this doesn't help me.

[typeorm/issues/1327](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/1327)
[nextauthjs/next-auth/issues/780](https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/issues/780)

Answer (score 0):

In your `UserEntity` you forgot to define `pets` as an array. It should be like below:

```js
@OneToMany(type => PetEntity, pet => pet.user)
pets: PetEntity[];
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, here is another case:

Once I deleted auto-generated index.ts content (I'm using Postgres with Typeform), I forgot to mention

```
AppDataSource.initialize().then(
async() => {
// pull rows fron db
})
```

Hope this helps.